# How to load bundle file and run the function from bundle correctly on mac?

Tags: c, macos, plugins

I'm trying to load `bundle` ,then run a function obtained from the bundle,but thre are some questions. What I expect is to display a UI when I run `mainproc`, Infact the UI does display, But the icon that should have been displayed on the UI was not displayed . the Icon located in resource directory and exists. I dont know why this happened?  I guess this is related to `CFBundleCopyResourceURL`.

I have no source code about this plugin. this is the code to load bundle.

```
    
 
CFStringRef g_bundlePath = nullptr;
CFBundleRef g_bundle = nullptr;

  if (g_bundlePath == nullptr) {

      g_bundlePath = CFSTR("/Users/third_party.plugin");


      CFURLRef bundleURL = CFURLCreateWithFileSystemPath(kCFAllocatorDefault, g_bundlePath, kCFURLPOSIXPathStyle, true);
      g_bundle = CFBundleCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, bundleURL);

      if (g_bundle) {
          bool success = CFBundleLoadExecutable(g_bundle);


      }

  }
  if (g_bundlePath != nullptr) {
  
      typedef void (*PLUGINPROC)(const int16, void*, intptr_t*, int16*);
      PLUGINPROC mainProc = (PLUGINPROC)CFBundleGetFunctionPointerForName((CFBundleRef)g_bundle, CFSTR("pluginrun"));
      mainProc(selector, filterParamBlock, data, result);

  }
```

the `third_party.plugin` type belong to `plugin` in bundle.more detail can get from this [bundle info](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/AboutBundles/AboutBundles.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000123i-CH100-SW1)

I run this code on `mac os sdk 10.15`.

Is there a problem running bundle in this way?
how can I display icons on UI by fixing the code ?